# Android alertdialog shows repeatedly

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, sensors

I am developing an app which can remind mobile users. When the sensor value changes, the dialog will show up. But if the sensor value changes constantly, the dialog will show up repeatedly and the preeceding dialog still exist! I want the dialog show up ONCE!

Below is my code:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if(event != null) {     
        if(event.values[0] <= 50){

            Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Alert");
            builder.setMessage("brightness too low"); 
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
              if(!alert.isShowing() ){
                alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                alert.show();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make Dialog as global so you can check before showing dialog that is it already showing..

Answer (score 0):

Please read about the APIs in Dialog @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing()

You can use this to determine if the dialog is already showing.

### General Advice

You should generally only have one Dialog instance that you control through the lifecycle of your Activity. Be **sure** to dismiss **and** set the dialog instance to null `onPause()` if applicable.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it!